# tox cannot install numpy

Tags: python, pyenv, tox

I have pyenv installed and these versions

```
pyenv versions
  system
  3.8.0
  3.9.16
* 3.10.1 (set by /home/me/.pyenv/version)
```

and I got this `tox.ini`

```
[tox]
envlist = unit_tests
skipsdist = True


[testenv]
install_command = pip install {opts} {packages}
deps =
    -rrequirements.txt

commands=
    py.test


[testenv:unit_tests]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/unit_tests
deps =
     {[testenv]deps}

setenv =
  PYTHONPATH=.

commands =
     python gradient_boosting_model/train_pipeline.py
     pytest \
           -s \
           -vv \
           {posargs:tests/}


[testenv:train]
envdir = {toxworkdir}/train
deps =
     {[testenv]deps}

setenv =
  PYTHONPATH=.

commands =
     python gradient_boosting_model/train_pipeline.py
```

the system python is 3.6.9

When I run tox , no matter in which version I get

```
tox
unit_tests create: /media/me/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/Udemy/testing-and-monitoring/testing-and-monitoring-ml-deployments/packages/gradient_boosting_model/.tox/unit_tests
unit_tests installdeps: -rrequirements.txt
ERROR: invocation failed (exit code 1), logfile: /media/me/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/Udemy/testing-and-monitoring/testing-and-monitoring-ml-deployments/packages/gradient_boosting_model/.tox/unit_tests/log/unit_tests-1.log
==================================================================== log start ====================================================================
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement numpy<1.21.0,>=1.20.0 (from versions: 1.3.0, 1.4.1, 1.5.0, 1.5.1, 1.6.0, 1.6.1, 1.6.2, 1.7.0, 1.7.1, 1.7.2, 1.8.0, 1.8.1, 1.8.2, 1.9.0, 1.9.1, 1.9.2, 1.9.3, 1.10.0.post2, 1.10.1, 1.10.2, 1.10.4, 1.11.0, 1.11.1, 1.11.2, 1.11.3, 1.12.0, 1.12.1, 1.13.0, 1.13.1, 1.13.3, 1.14.0, 1.14.1, 1.14.2, 1.14.3, 1.14.4, 1.14.5, 1.14.6, 1.15.0, 1.15.1, 1.15.2, 1.15.3, 1.15.4, 1.16.0, 1.16.1, 1.16.2, 1.16.3, 1.16.4, 1.16.5, 1.16.6, 1.17.0, 1.17.1, 1.17.2, 1.17.3, 1.17.4, 1.17.5, 1.18.0, 1.18.1, 1.18.2, 1.18.3, 1.18.4, 1.18.5, 1.19.0, 1.19.1, 1.19.2, 1.19.3, 1.19.4, 1.19.5)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for numpy<1.21.0,>=1.20.0

===================================================================== log end =====================================================================
ERROR: could not install deps [-rrequirements.txt]; v = InvocationError('/media/me/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/Udemy/testing-and-monitoring/testing-and-monitoring-ml-deployments/packages/gradient_boosting_model/.tox/unit_tests/bin/pip install -rrequirements.txt', 1)
_____________________________________________________________________ summary _____________________________________________________________________
ERROR:   unit_tests: could not install deps [-rrequirements.txt]; v = InvocationError('/media/me/cbe421fe-1303-4821-9392-a849bfdd00e2/MyStudy/Udemy/testing-and-monitoring/testing-and-monitoring-ml-deployments/packages/gradient_boosting_model/.tox/unit_tests/bin/pip install -rrequirements.txt', 1)
```

the `requirements.txt` file is

```
# ML requirements
numpy>=1.20.0,<1.21.0
pandas>=1.3.5,<1.4.0
scikit-learn>=1.0.2,<1.1.0
feature-engine>=1.0.2,<1.1.0
joblib>=1.0.1,<1.1.0

# config parsing
strictyaml>=1.3.2,<1.4.0
ruamel.yaml==0.16.12
pydantic>=1.8.1,<1.9.0

# validation
marshmallow>=3.2.2,<4.0

# packaging
setuptools>=41.4.0,<42.0.0
wheel>=0.33.6,<0.34.0

# testing requirements
pytest>=5.3.2,<6.0.0
```

At first I thought it was because the original python version is old but even when I run it with python 10 it does not work.

What can it be solved?

Answer (score 0):

numpy 1.2.0 requires Python 3.7 or higher.

As you do not specify a Python version in your tox configuration file, tox will test with the version it is installed, which is Python 3.6, which results in no fitting numpy version available.

Also see https://pypi.org/project/numpy/1.20.0/#data

You would need to set an `envlist` with the appropriate Python version.

Please note that toy does not install Python versions, they must be available on the path already, e.g. provided by pyenv, as you do. For pyenv you need to set the Python versions as globally available, see the pyenv readme.

Comment: my doubt is that when `pyenv versions` indicates the python is 3.10 why does tox still use the 3.6 version? (I set that suing `pyenv global 3.10.1`)

Comment: As mentioned above. toy was installed with Python 3.6, and you do not specify a Python version in tox.iini, so it uses the one it was installed with. PS I am the maintainer of tox.